# Springboot Application Failed to start because of a bean problem

Tags: spring-boot, service, javabeans, crud, abstract

I am studying basic development practice. 
While creating a CRUD Service and trying to abstract the service, an error related to the bean occurred.

here is my code

1.CrudInterface

```
public interface CrudInterface<Req, Res> {

Header<Res> create(Header<Req> request);

Header<Res> read(Long id);

Header<Res> update(Header<Req> request);

Header delete(Long id);
}
```

2.CrudController.java

```
@Component
public class CrudController<Req,Res,Entity> implements 
CrudInterface<Req,Res> {

@Autowired(required = false)
protected BaseService<Req,Res,Entity> entityBaseService;

@Override
@PostMapping("")
public Header<Res> create(@RequestBody Header<Req> request) {
    return entityBaseService.create(request);
}

@Override
@GetMapping("{id}")
public Header<Res> read(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return entityBaseService.read(id);
}

@Override
@PutMapping("")
public Header<Res> update(@RequestBody Header<Req> request) {
    return entityBaseService.update(request);
}

@Override
@DeleteMapping("{id}")
public Header delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return entityBaseService.delete(id);
}
}
```

3.UserApiController.java

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
public class UserApiController extends 
CrudController<UserApiRequest, UserApiResponse, User> {
}
```

4.BaseService.java

```
@Component
public abstract class BaseService<Req,Res,Entity> implements 
CrudInterface<Req,Res> {

@Autowired(required = false)
protected JpaRepository<Entity,Long> baseRepository;


}
```

5.UserApiLogicService

```
@Service
public class UserApiLogicService extends 
BaseService<UserApiRequest, UserApiResponse,User> {



@Override
public Header<UserApiResponse> create(Header<UserApiRequest> request) {

    UserApiRequest body = request.getData();

    User user = User.builder()
            .account(body.getAccount())
            .password(body.getPassword())
            .status(UserStatus.REGISTERED)
            .phoneNumber(body.getPhoneNumber())
            .email(body.getEmail())
            .registeredAt(LocalDateTime.now())
            .build();

    User newUser = baseRepository.save(user);


    return response(newUser);
}

@Override
public Header<UserApiResponse> read(Long id) {

    return baseRepository.findById(id)
            .map(user -> response(user))
            .orElseGet(
                    () -> Header.ERROR("데이터 없음")
            );
}

@Override
public Header<UserApiResponse> update(Header<UserApiRequest> request) {

    UserApiRequest body = request.getData();


    Optional<User> optional = baseRepository.findById(body.getId());

    return optional.map(user -> {

        user.setAccount(body.getAccount())
                .setPassword(body.getPassword())
                .setStatus(body.getStatus())
                .setPhoneNumber(body.getPhoneNumber())
                .setEmail(body.getEmail())
                .setRegisteredAt(body.getRegisteredAt())
                .setUnregisteredAt(body.getUnregisteredAt());
        return user;

    })
            .map(user -> baseRepository.save(user)) // update -> newUser
            .map(updateUser -> response(updateUser)) // userApiResponse
            .orElseGet(() -> Header.ERROR("데이터 없음"));
}

@Override
public Header delete(Long id) {

    Optional<User> optional = baseRepository.findById(id);

    // 2. repository -> delete
    return optional.map(user -> {
        baseRepository.delete(user);
        return Header.OK();
    })
            .orElseGet(() -> Header.ERROR("데이터 없음"));

}

private Header<UserApiResponse> response(User user) {

    UserApiResponse userApiResponse = UserApiResponse.builder()
            .id(user.getId())
            .account(user.getAccount())
            .password(user.getPassword())
            .email(user.getEmail())
            .phoneNumber(user.getPhoneNumber())
            .status(user.getStatus())
            .registeredAt(user.getRegisteredAt())
            .unregisteredAt(user.getUnregisteredAt())
            .build();


    return Header.OK(userApiResponse);
}
}
```

6.CategoryApiLogicService.java

```
@Service
public class CategoryApiLogicService extends 
BaseService<CategoryApiRequest, CategoryApiResponse,Category> {


@Override
public Header<CategoryApiResponse> create(Header<CategoryApiRequest> request) {
    CategoryApiRequest body = request.getData();

    Category category = Category.builder()
            .type(body.getType())
            .title(body.getTitle())
            .createdAt(body.getCreatedAt())
            .createdBy(body.getCreatedBy())
            .build();

    Category newCategory = baseRepository.save(category);

    return response(newCategory);
}

@Override
public Header<CategoryApiResponse> read(Long id) {
    return baseRepository.findById(id)
            .map(category -> response(category))
            .orElseGet(()-> Header.ERROR("데이터 없음"));
}

@Override
public Header<CategoryApiResponse> update(Header<CategoryApiRequest> request) {
    CategoryApiRequest body = request.getData();

    return baseRepository.findById(body.getId())
            .map(category -> {
                category
                        .setType(body.getType())
                        .setTitle(body.getTitle())
                        .setCreatedAt(body.getCreatedAt())
                        .setCreatedBy(body.getCreatedBy());
                return category;
            })
            .map(changeCategory -> baseRepository.save(changeCategory))
            .map(newCategory -> response(newCategory))
            .orElseGet(()->Header.ERROR("데이터 없음"));
}

@Override
public Header delete(Long id) {
    return baseRepository.findById(id)
            .map(category -> {
                baseRepository.delete(category);
                return Header.OK();
            })
            .orElseGet(()->Header.ERROR("데이터 없음"));
}

private Header<CategoryApiResponse> response(Category category){
    CategoryApiResponse body = CategoryApiResponse.builder()
            .id(category.getId())
            .type(category.getType())
            .title(category.getTitle())
            .createdAt(category.getCreatedAt())
            .createdBy(category.getCreatedBy())
            .build();

    return Header.OK(body);
}
}
```

8.ItemApiLogicService.java

```
@Service
public class ItemApiLogicService extends 
BaseService<ItemApiRequest,ItemApiResponse,Item>  {


@Autowired
private PartnerRepository partnerRepository;

@Override
public Header<ItemApiResponse> create(Header<ItemApiRequest> request) {

    ItemApiRequest body = request.getData();

    Item item = Item.builder()
            .status(body.getStatus())
            .name(body.getName())
            .title(body.getTitle())
            .content(body.getContent())
            .price(body.getPrice())
            .brandName(body.getBrandName())
            .registeredAt(LocalDateTime.now())
            .partner(partnerRepository.getOne(body.getPartnerId()))
            .build();

    Item newItem = baseRepository.save(item);

    return response(newItem);
}

@Override
public Header<ItemApiResponse> read(Long id) {
    return baseRepository.findById(id)
            .map(user -> response(user))
            .orElseGet(
                    () -> Header.ERROR("데이터 없음")
            );
}

@Override
public Header<ItemApiResponse> update(Header<ItemApiRequest> request) {

    ItemApiRequest body = request.getData();

    return baseRepository.findById(body.getId())
            .map(entityItem -> {
                entityItem
                        .setStatus(body.getStatus())
                        .setName(body.getName())
                        .setTitle(body.getTitle())
                        .setContent(body.getContent())
                        .setPrice(body.getPrice())
                        .setBrandName(body.getBrandName())
                        .setRegisteredAt(body.getRegisteredAt())
                        .setUnregisteredAt(body.getUnregisteredAt());

                return entityItem;
            })
            .map(newEntityItem -> baseRepository.save(newEntityItem))
            .map(item -> response(item))
            .orElseGet(() -> Header.ERROR("데이터 없음"));
}

@Override
public Header delete(Long id) {
    return baseRepository.findById(id)
            .map(item -> {
                baseRepository.delete(item);
                return Header.OK();
            })
            .orElseGet(() -> Header.ERROR("데이터없음"));
}

private Header<ItemApiResponse> response(Item item) {

    ItemApiResponse body = ItemApiResponse.builder()
            .id(item.getId())
            .status(item.getStatus())
            .name(item.getName())
            .title(item.getTitle())
            .content(item.getContent())
            .price(item.getPrice())
            .brandName(item.getBrandName())
            .registeredAt(item.getRegisteredAt())
            .unregisteredAt(item.getUnregisteredAt())
            .partnerId(item.getPartner().getId())
            .build();

    return Header.OK(body);
}
}
```

and here is my error message

```
ERROR 4516 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

Field entityBaseService in com.example.admin.controller.CrudController required a single bean, but 6 were found:
- categoryApiLogicService: defined in file [D:\~\service\CategoryApiLogicService.class]
- itemApiLogicService: defined in file [D:\~\service\ItemApiLogicService.class]
- orderDetailApiLogicService: defined in file [D:\~\service\OrderDetailApiLogicService.class]
- orderGroupApiLogicService: defined in file [D:\~\service\OrderGroupApiLogicService.class]
- partnerApiLogicService: defined in file [D:\~\service\PartnerApiLogicService.class]
- userApiLogicService: defined in file [D:\~\service\UserApiLogicService.class]
```

Thanks for reading the long story. 
I hope you catch the error.

Comment: Show source code of `CategoryApiLogicService.java` and `ItemApiLogicService.java`

Comment: It is almost similar to user. I edited my post. 
but I solved the problem with the answer below. Thanks for ur help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe has 6 classes implement `BaseService` and you decide the abstract class with name `entityBaseService`, so Spring cannot bind exactly the bean you want.

You can use @primary mask on a class for default bean or using @qualifier to bind with the bean name

prefer: `http://zetcode.com/springboot/qualifier`

Comment: I use `@primary` mask on a `UserApiLogicService.java` class and it worked! Thank you.</br>
I'll also study `@qualifier`